# How do I specify entry points or find errors in my code to stop "Program has more than one entry point." in C#?

Tags: c#

[image: error image] I have just started learning C# a few weeks ago and do have a year and half of experience in Python, so it would be better if i could get a more detailed explanation on why am i getting this error. I have tried searching on google to see if anyone has gotten this error before, but i am not able to understand the solutions and how to put in the solution.  Here's the code, find anything wrong?

```cs
using System;

namespace RectangleApplication
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        double length;
        double width;

        public void Acceptdetails()
        {
            length = 4.5;
            width = 3.5;
        }

        public double GetArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("length: {0}", length);
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
            Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
        }
    }

    class ExecuteRectangle
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Acceptdetails();
            r.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only have one `Main` method in your entire program.

Comment: If Visual Studio generated your project for you (e.g. if you chose "New Project"/"Windows Forms") then it may have added a `Main` method for you already. Search your code base.

Comment: The error is on line 9 as per the terminal, also remember that i am very new to C# and Object oriented programming

Comment: @SiddharthHarish: And what is line 9?  How are you compiling this application?  Is this a single code file that you are compiling on the command-line?  If so, what command are you using?  What is the exact and complete output generated by that command?  Or are you using an IDE like Visual Studio?  If so, what is the project structure?  Are there other code files?

Comment: A Class project does not have a main.  A console project should have only one main.  If you add a class project to a console project and the class project has a main you will have two main entry points.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/main-method-in-c-sharp/

Comment: code 9 - 'Double length

Comment: @SiddharthHarish: `double length;` (which is **not** the same thing as "Double length") is not causing the problem.  The code shown compiles and runs without error.  We can appreciate that you're new to C#, but you're going to have to provide information about the problem in order for anybody to help.  Clearly there is more going on than just the code shown.

Comment: @David "double length" is line nine and i Am using 'Visual studio for mac' to edit and run the code. This is only my second script following this tutorial - (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_tutorial.pdf), and no other C# code files.

Comment: @SiddharthHarish: Perhaps you could update the question to include a screen shot of what you're seeing, including the error output and the project structure.

Comment: I copy pasted your code exactly into a new console application using VS 2022 and it ran just fine. There is more going on in your project structure than you realize I'm guessing.

Comment: The code actually seems to show an error in VS code, then after a ~5-10 secs the output is given. I think i was just overreacting. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is correct.

If you [read about the `Main()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/main-method-in-c-sharp/) method, you see that it has the following requirements to be an entry point

- Must be `static` method inside a class
- Must be called `Main()`
- Can have `public`, `internal`, `protected` or `private` access modifiers
- Can have arguments capturing the command line arguments

  ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
   }
  ```
- Can have zero arguments

  ```
   static void Main()
   {
   }
  ```
- Must have only **one** such method defined within each project.

  In your case there might be another file, called `Program.cs` that also defines a `Main()` method. Delete this other file, or move the main method from `class ExecuteRectangle` to `class Program`.
- For winforms applications the main methods loads the main form and displays it using `Application.Run()`.

---

On a related note, since you are learning about C# and OOP, consider the code below with similar functionality as yours, but with standard C# syntax, that uses properties, constructors and the `ToString()` method to generate string representations of objects

```
class Rectangle
{
    double length;
    double width;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get { return length; }
        set
        {
            length = value;
        }
    }
    public double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            width = value;
        }
    }
    public double Area
    {
        get { return length * width; }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $@"Length {Length}
Width {Width}
Area {Area}";
}

class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4.5, 3.5);
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        //Length: 4.5
        //Width: 3.5
        //Area: 15.75

        r.Length = 6.5;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        //Length: 6.5
        //Width: 3.5
        //Area: 22.75

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I specifically made the properties mutable (can be changes) because this is a common design choice. If the properties were to be immutable then there wouldn't be a `set` method, and the fields would have a `readonly` keyword in front of them.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out that VS code was just giving a random error but showed the output bit later.

Comment: @JebKerman - see edits above. I decided to include a mini lesson on how to setup properties, something that maybe you have not used with `Python`. Properties is the defacto way to get or set information from a class in C#.

Answer (score 3):

In the error it says line: 9 File: Program.cs

Your code is in EmptyCSharpFile.cs

There is another .cs file called Program.cs that is in your project that has a `Main` method, and that is what is causing the problem. Double clicking on an error should take you to the line of code that is failing.

Comment: Really helpful to know. I am also creating new consoles from terminal which really helps. :)